# Inconsistent surface behaviour in Three.js

Tags: three.js, surface, light

when I set a point light at a `THREE.BoxGeometry` object it looks like this:
[THREE.BoxGeometry with point light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLae1.png)

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight (0xffffff, 1, 100);
light.position.set (10, 10, 10);
scene.add (light);
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry (1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial ();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh (geometry, material);
scene.add (cube);
```

When I now set a point light at a `THREE.PolyhedronGeometry` object it looks like this:
[THREE.PolyhedronGeometry with point light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfEQW.png)

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight (0xffffff, 1, 100);
light.position.set (10, 10, 10);
scene.add (light);
var geometry = new THREE.PolyhedronGeometry (vertices, faces, 1, 0);
var vertices = [-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1];
var faces = [2,1,0,0,3,2,0,4,7,7,3,0,0,1,5,5,4,0,1,2,6,6,5,1,2,3,7,7,6,2,4,5,6,6,7,4];
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial ();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh (geometry, material);
scene.add (cube);
```

I want to know, where this behaviour comes from and how I can manage to make polyhedrons' faces behave as nice as boxs?

I read that it might be related to `geometry.computeFaceNormals()`.

So I tried it out, but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

when something is different with how light behaves on a surface, first candidates to look at are normals

this is true for the box face

```
boxGeometry.faces[i].normal.equals(boxGeometry.faces[i].vertexNormals[j]);//true
```

so box has only simple normal for each face

the polyhedron has different face normal from the vertex normals

```
polyhedronGeo.faces[i].normal.equals(polyhedronGeo.faces[i].vertexNormals[j]);//not true
```

and some of the vertex normals are not equal among each other

```
polyhedronGeo.faces[i].vertexNormals[j].equals(polyhedronGeo.faces[i].vertexNormals[k]);
//not true for some j,k
```

that is why the light looks ~shadowy - normal is interpolated for the shader from vertexNormals
to modify the polyhedron to look like box just change the vertex notmals to match the face normal

as for

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
```

it will only compute the face normals, not the vertexNormals

there is another function

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

but that would create vertex normals as are in polyhedron

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Derte. Your reflection got me closer to the point. So with advanced keywords I found this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1982

The answer to my question is this line, flattening shading for "free forms":

```
material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
```